# How can I fix 'page not redirecting properly' error with nginx and Certbot SSL?

Tags: nginx, ssl, server, certbot

I have ubuntu base server there i want to setup the nginx with certbot in docker, when I try to access the website it shows  page is not redirecting properly but with port 9001 I am able to access the website. please note that I am service two different websites on port 80 and 9001.

here is my nginx conf

```
# Upstream configuration
upstream botpress_server {
    server botpress:3000;
}

# Disable sending the server identification
server_tokens off;

add_header Content-Security-Policy "frame-ancestors *;";

# Configure the cache for static assets
proxy_cache_path /srv/nginx_cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=my_cache:10m max_size=10g inactive=60m use_temp_path=off;

# Set the max file size for uploads (make sure it is larger than the configured media size in botpress.config.json)
client_max_body_size 15M;

# Server Block for SSL and Port 9000
server {
    listen 9000 ssl;
    listen [::]:9000 ssl;
    server_name redladdersa.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/redladdersa.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/redladdersa.com/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

    # Enable caching of assets by NGINX to reduce load on the server
    location ~ .*/assets/.* {
        proxy_cache my_cache;
        proxy_ignore_headers Cache-Control;
        proxy_hide_header Cache-Control;
        proxy_hide_header Pragma;
        proxy_pass http://botpress_server;
        proxy_cache_valid any 30m;
        proxy_set_header Cache-Control max-age=30;
        add_header Cache-Control max-age=30;
    }

    # Add specific headers for WebSockets
    location /socket.io/ {
        proxy_pass http://botpress_server/socket.io/;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
    }

    # All other requests should be directed to the server
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://botpress_server;
    }
}

# Server Block for SSL and Port 9001
server {
    listen 9001 ssl;
    listen [::]:9001 ssl;
    server_name redladdersa.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/redladdersa.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/redladdersa.com/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://botpress_server;
    }
}

# Server Block for Laravel Server on Port 80 with SSL redirect
server {
    listen 80 ssl;
    index index.php index.html;
    root /var/www/html/public;
    server_name redladdersa.com;

    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.php?$args;
    }

    location /css/ {
        alias /var/www/html/public/css/;
    }

    location /vendor/ {
        alias /var/www/html/public/vendor/;
    }

    location /js/ {
        alias /var/html/public/js/;
    }

    location /images/ {
        alias /var/www/html/public/images/;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass laravel-app:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
    

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/redladdersa.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/redladdersa.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot

    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

    location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        root /var/www/certbot;
    }
    
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    server_name redladdersa.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/redladdersa.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/redladdersa.com/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

    location / {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
}
```

Comment: *"return 301 https://$host$request_uri;"* - this basically says to redirect to the same page which the user have accessed. It is unclear what you actually want to do though and this unclear what the proper redirect should be. Apart from that you have a very strange setup of using ssl on port 80 - which is usually plain http (not https).

Comment: There are two ports one is 80 and another is 9001. I want to add the ssl for both. when the user just enter the domain name it should display the port 80 website and if they enter the port along with domain it should show the port 9001 website. in my case the domain with port 9001 is working fine

Comment: Port 80 is used for http, port 443 for https. Setting up port 80 with ssl will only lead to strange errors if the user tries to access the site with plain HTTP. If the URL used is https w/o port then the browser will use 443 anyway, not 80.

Comment: @SteffenUllrichcan you please provide me the proper code please

Comment: Again, it is unclear what you want to be redirect to in the first place. Right now you specify only that it does not work, but you don't specify what the expected outcome (apart from "should work" - whatever this means) is. It might actually be that you don't want to redirect to anything but display the content, but this is unknown to me.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I want to redirect to port 80 and display the website directly when only domain name is entered